# How to pass in 2D array (matrix) into function?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is going back to basics but for some reason Visual Studio keeps giving me an error. Something is wrong with my function's parameters.

What am I doing wrong? I pass in the dimension of the matrix (NxN) but I must be missing something.

These are the errors it gives me, and it confuses more than clarifies:

an array may not have elements of this type (the function parameter)

'matrix' missing subscript (the function parameter)

'void print(const int,char [][])': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char [3][3]' to 'char [][]' (where I call the function in main)

```
// Function that has problems
void print(const int size, char matrix[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return;
}

// MAIN
int main() {
    const int n = 3;
    char matrix[n][n] = {'a', 'b', 'c',
                         'h', 'i', 'd', 
                         'g', 'f', 'e'};

    print(n, matrix); // Calling function here

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang says: #1 with x86-64 gcc (trunk) :2:42: error: declaration of 'matrix' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first - godbolt.org/g/qgnHTy

Remember that in order to do a array2d[i][j] lookup, it must be able to access the element at i * length + j but the compiler doesn't know what the length of matrix is because you didn't put it in the type. The compiler doesn't know that the size parameter is related.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Function that has problems
template<int size> 
void print(char matrix[][size]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return;
}

// MAIN
int main() {
    constexpr int n = 3;
    char matrix[n][n] = {'a', 'b', 'c',
                         'h', 'i', 'd', 
                         'g', 'f', 'e'};

    print<n>(matrix); // Calling function here

    return 0;
}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/g/YWDgk5

Comment: Thank you! I don't really understand templating so I need to read up on that. Is this templating you just did called function templating?

Comment: Can this same method be applied to multiple template parameters? ex: templates<int row,  int col>. I could call the function like this: print<x,  y>(matrix)?

Comment: yes.   Template parameteres basically rewrite the function as `void print(const int size, char matrix[4][5]) {` if you pass template parameters of row=4 and col=5 in.   so that the type exactly matches what you're passing in

Comment: I found a work around for my issue (pass array by reference), but that actually did not work for me! If you see my other post, it did not let me pass in those template arguments. :/ Do you know why?

Comment: @JessicaWang I just answered your other question